# Solve the matrix equation.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How do I solve $\begin{pmatrix}
2 &1 \\ 
 1& 2
\end{pmatrix}X-X\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-1 \\ 
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
 1&-1 
\end{pmatrix}$. I think i need to use the inverse but I do not know really how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  just perform matrix multiplication:
for 
$$
X=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} \\
 x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
you get
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x_{1,1}-x_{1,2}+x_{2,1}-1 & x_{1,1}+x_{1,2}+x_{2,2}-1 \\
 x_{1,1}+x_{2,1}-x_{2,2}-1 & x_{1,2}+x_{2,1}+x_{2,2}+1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=0
$$
which gives
$$
\left\{x_{1,1}=\frac{7}{5},x_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{5},x_{2,1}=-\frac{3}{5},x_{2,2}=
   -\frac{1}{5}\right\}
$$

Comment: Oh thanks :D. How did you multiply them soo fast?

Comment: I would lie If I said I made it by hand :D

Comment: This is a particular case of Sylvester equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)

Comment: and how do i solve that system of equations?

Comment: the knowledge that this is a Sylvester equation does not help to solve it anyhow differently/faster. The solution above cannot be significantly simplified (which is in particular clear from the answer which is quite ugly).

Comment: Three things. 1)  I just wanted to say that this question belongs to a larger domain 2) I agree that for $2 \times 2$ matrices, it is not interesting, but in the case you deal with  $n \times n$ matrices with $n \geq 4$, you will be happy to have the general formula (as given in Wikipedia article). 3) Moreover, an increasing number of software implement Sylvester equation as a specific function in their new releases (Mathematica, Matlab...).